# javascript Uncaught TypeError for map

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error if i use map in my script. How to resolve this error?

I am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Js Script:

```
 var stringval="global $1200"; 
 var getVal=stringval.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
```

Comment: it works fine buddy. Whats the error?

Comment: Which version of ECMA-Script do you use?

Comment: Getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Comment: Please, be more specific. Which browser do you use? Which version of Javascript do you use? Without those setup information no one will be able to help you solve your problem.

Comment: @RojaS are you using any older version of IE browser? As your code works fine in current browser. Check  link  for more details. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) return `Array<string> | null`.

- If match is found, an array of matched string will be returned.
- If no match is found, `null` will be rendered.

So in you case, if the string does not have any number, it will return `null` causing the script to break.

**Sample:**

```js
function getNumber(stringval) {
  return stringval.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
}

var stringval = "global $1200";
console.log(getNumber(stringval))
console.log(getNumber('Hello World'))
```

---

A simple way to solve this is to add a check for existence of match:

```js
function getNumber(stringval) {
  // You can set any value based on your requirement
  var defaultValue = undefined;
  var matches = stringval.match(/\d+/g)
  return matches !== null ? matches.map(Number) : defaultValue;
}

var stringval = "global $1200";
console.log(getNumber(stringval))
console.log(getNumber('Hello World'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much